# jQuery - Checking which button was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two buttons:

```
<input type="button" name="hideAll" value="Hide Descriptions"/>
<input type="button" name="showAll" value="Show Descriptions"/>
```

Using jQuery, how do I tell which button was clicked?

Comment: Hi Naz, I can see your are not a complete newbie to StackOverflow, but you still may find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, especially that part: "Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and **any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself.** "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class that your buttons share...

```
<input class="mybutton" type="button" name="hideAll" value="Hide Descriptions"/>
<input class="mybutton" type="button" name="showAll" value="Show Descriptions"/>

$(function() {
    $('.mybutton').on('click', function() {
        var isClicked = this.attr('name');

        if (isClicked === 'hideAll') {
           ...
        }
        if (isClicked === 'showAll') {
           ...
        }
    });
});
```

Depending on your needs and scope, you could also make `isClicked` a global variable which will be available outside the click event.

```
isClicked = this.attr('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="button"]').on('click', function() {
    // which button was clicked?
    alert($(this).attr('name') + ' was clicked');
});
```